# SignalR 2 updates only on page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I've developed an SR 2 application using an online example. It's not an MVC version and I coded in C#.

I query against a database with one table that contains one row of data with many fields.

My problem is that the data displays on initial page load but not after data changes in database. If I refresh the page manually, the data updates on the page, reflecting the changes in the database. Any clues? If you need more information let me know.

Thanks,
script on default.aspx page. iData is an array containing values to be displayed.

```
$(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var wip = $.connection.wipHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        wip.client.receiveWip = function (iData) {
            arr = iData.split(',');
}
});
```

Hub code here:

```
[HubName("wipHub")]
public class WipHub : Hub
{
    string param = "";
    int TML1 = 0; int TML2 = 0; int TMT1 = 0; int TMT2 = 0;
    int MLT1 = 0; int SNL1 = 0; int CAV1 = 0; int IBL1 = 0; int PAW1 = 0; int PLB1 = 0;
    int MLT2 = 0; int SNL2 = 0; int CAV2 = 0; int IBL2 = 0; int PAW2 = 0; int PLB2 = 0;
    int MLT3 = 0; int SNL3 = 0; int CAV3 = 0; int IBL3 = 0; int PAW3 = 0; int PLB3 = 0;
    int MLT4 = 0; int SNL4 = 0; int CAV4 = 0; int IBL4 = 0; int PAW4 = 0; int PLB4 = 0;
    int MLT5 = 0; int SNL5 = 0; int CAV5 = 0; int IBL5 = 0; int PAW5 = 0; int PLB5 = 0;

    [HubMethodName("sendWip")]
    public void SendWip()
    {
        using ( var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString) )
        {
            string query = "Select MLT1,MLT2,MLT3,MLT4,MLT5,SNL1,SNL2,SNL3,SNL4,SNL5,CAV1,CAV2,CAV3,CAV4,CAV5,IBL1,IBL2,IBL3,IBL4,IBL5,PAW1,PAW2,PAW3,PAW4,PAW5,PLB1,PLB2,PLB3,PLB4,PLB5,TML1,TML2,TMT1,TMT2 FROM WIP_Table Where ID=" + 1;
            connection.Open();

            using ( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection) )
            {
                command.Notification = null;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                if(connection.State== ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString);
                }

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
                if ( dt.Rows.Count > 0 )
                {
                    MLT1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT1"].ToString());
                    MLT2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT2"].ToString());
                    MLT3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT3"].ToString());
                    MLT4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT4"].ToString());
                    MLT5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT5"].ToString());
                    SNL1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL1"].ToString());
                    SNL2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL2"].ToString());
                    SNL3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL3"].ToString());
                    SNL4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL4"].ToString());
                    SNL5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL5"].ToString());
                    CAV1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV1"].ToString());
                    CAV2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV2"].ToString());
                    CAV3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV3"].ToString());
                    CAV4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV4"].ToString());
                    CAV5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV5"].ToString());
                    IBL1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL1"].ToString());
                    IBL2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL2"].ToString());
                    IBL3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL3"].ToString());
                    IBL4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL4"].ToString());
                    IBL5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL5"].ToString());
                    PAW1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW1"].ToString());
                    PAW2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW2"].ToString());
                    PAW3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW3"].ToString());
                    PAW4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW4"].ToString());
                    PAW5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW5"].ToString());
                    PLB1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB1"].ToString());
                    PLB2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB2"].ToString());
                    PLB3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB3"].ToString());
                    PLB4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB4"].ToString());
                    PLB5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB5"].ToString());
                    TML1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TML1"].ToString());
                    TML2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TML2"].ToString());
                    TMT1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TMT1"].ToString());
                    TMT2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TMT2"].ToString());

                    param = MLT1 + ","
                                 + MLT2
                                 + ","
                                 + MLT3
                                 + ","
                                 + MLT4
                                 + ","
                                 + MLT5
                                 + ","
                                 + SNL1
                                 + ","
                                 + SNL2
                                 + ","
                                 + SNL3
                                 + ","
                                 + SNL4
                                 + ","
                                 + SNL5
                                 + ","
                                 + CAV1
                                 + ","
                                 + CAV2
                                 + ","
                                 + CAV3
                                 + ","
                                 + CAV4
                                 + ","
                                 + CAV5
                                 + ","
                                 + IBL1
                                 + ","
                                 + IBL2
                                 + ","
                                 + IBL3
                                 + ","
                                 + IBL4
                                 + ","
                                 + IBL5
                                + ","
                                + PAW1
                                + ","
                                + PAW2
                                + ","
                                + PAW3
                                + ","
                                + PAW4
                                + ","
                                + PAW5
                                + ","
                                + PLB1
                                + ","
                                + PLB2
                                + ","
                                + PLB3
                                + ","
                                + PLB4
                                + ","
                                + PLB5
                                +","
                                + TML1
                                + ","
                                + TML2
                                + ","
                                + TMT1
                                + ","
                                + TMT2;

                }

            }

        }

        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<WipHub>();
        context.Clients.All.ReceiveWip(param);

    }
    private void dependency_OnChange( object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change )
        {
            WipHub thisHub = new WipHub();
            thisHub.SendWip();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server

"You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its methods from your own code on the server; all that is done for you by the SignalR Hubs pipeline. SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a client connects, disconnects, or makes a method call to the server."

I would recommend that you make the follwing tutorial:http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

After that you should know how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In hub class you need to write some iterative code so that you can call context.Clients.All.ReceiveWip(param) repeatedly.
You can use System.Timers.Timer as:

```
 public class WipHub : Hub
    {
        public static System.Timers.Timer _Timer;
        public void startWip()
        {
            if (_Timer == null)
            {
                _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
                _Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
                _Timer.Enabled = true;
                _Timer.Interval = 1000;
            }
        }
        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Clients.All.ReceiveWip(SendWip());
        }


        public string SendWip()
        {
            string param = "";
            int TML1 = 0; int TML2 = 0; int TMT1 = 0; int TMT2 = 0;
            int MLT1 = 0; int SNL1 = 0; int CAV1 = 0; int IBL1 = 0; int PAW1 = 0; int PLB1 = 0;
            int MLT2 = 0; int SNL2 = 0; int CAV2 = 0; int IBL2 = 0; int PAW2 = 0; int PLB2 = 0;
            int MLT3 = 0; int SNL3 = 0; int CAV3 = 0; int IBL3 = 0; int PAW3 = 0; int PLB3 = 0;
            int MLT4 = 0; int SNL4 = 0; int CAV4 = 0; int IBL4 = 0; int PAW4 = 0; int PLB4 = 0;
            int MLT5 = 0; int SNL5 = 0; int CAV5 = 0; int IBL5 = 0; int PAW5 = 0; int PLB5 = 0;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string query = "Select MLT1,MLT2,MLT3,MLT4,MLT5,SNL1,SNL2,SNL3,SNL4,SNL5,CAV1,CAV2,CAV3,CAV4,CAV5,IBL1,IBL2,IBL3,IBL4,IBL5,PAW1,PAW2,PAW3,PAW4,PAW5,PLB1,PLB2,PLB3,PLB4,PLB5,TML1,TML2,TMT1,TMT2 FROM WIP_Table Where ID=" + 1;
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString);
                    }

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MLT1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT1"].ToString());
                        MLT2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT2"].ToString());
                        MLT3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT3"].ToString());
                        MLT4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT4"].ToString());
                        MLT5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MLT5"].ToString());
                        SNL1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL1"].ToString());
                        SNL2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL2"].ToString());
                        SNL3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL3"].ToString());
                        SNL4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL4"].ToString());
                        SNL5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["SNL5"].ToString());
                        CAV1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV1"].ToString());
                        CAV2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV2"].ToString());
                        CAV3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV3"].ToString());
                        CAV4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV4"].ToString());
                        CAV5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["CAV5"].ToString());
                        IBL1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL1"].ToString());
                        IBL2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL2"].ToString());
                        IBL3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL3"].ToString());
                        IBL4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL4"].ToString());
                        IBL5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["IBL5"].ToString());
                        PAW1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW1"].ToString());
                        PAW2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW2"].ToString());
                        PAW3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW3"].ToString());
                        PAW4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW4"].ToString());
                        PAW5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PAW5"].ToString());
                        PLB1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB1"].ToString());
                        PLB2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB2"].ToString());
                        PLB3 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB3"].ToString());
                        PLB4 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB4"].ToString());
                        PLB5 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PLB5"].ToString());
                        TML1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TML1"].ToString());
                        TML2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TML2"].ToString());
                        TMT1 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TMT1"].ToString());
                        TMT2 = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TMT2"].ToString());

                        param = MLT1 + ","
                                     + MLT2
                                     + ","
                                     + MLT3
                                     + ","
                                     + MLT4
                                     + ","
                                     + MLT5
                                     + ","
                                     + SNL1
                                     + ","
                                     + SNL2
                                     + ","
                                     + SNL3
                                     + ","
                                     + SNL4
                                     + ","
                                     + SNL5
                                     + ","
                                     + CAV1
                                     + ","
                                     + CAV2
                                     + ","
                                     + CAV3
                                     + ","
                                     + CAV4
                                     + ","
                                     + CAV5
                                     + ","
                                     + IBL1
                                     + ","
                                     + IBL2
                                     + ","
                                     + IBL3
                                     + ","
                                     + IBL4
                                     + ","
                                     + IBL5
                                    + ","
                                    + PAW1
                                    + ","
                                    + PAW2
                                    + ","
                                    + PAW3
                                    + ","
                                    + PAW4
                                    + ","
                                    + PAW5
                                    + ","
                                    + PLB1
                                    + ","
                                    + PLB2
                                    + ","
                                    + PLB3
                                    + ","
                                    + PLB4
                                    + ","
                                    + PLB5
                                    + ","
                                    + TML1
                                    + ","
                                    + TML2
                                    + ","
                                    + TMT1
                                    + ","
                                    + TMT2;

                    }

                }

            }
            return param;
        }
    }
```

And on client side  as:

```
$(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var wip = $.connection.wipHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        wip.client.receiveWip = function (iData) {
            arr = iData.split(',');
}
$.connection.hub.start(function() {
wip.server.startWip();
});
});
```

You can follow the link http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/DotNet/CSharp/SignalR-web-client-(Javascript-Client)-without-ASP_NET/20203